# Why does BottomSheetDialog turn status bar black?

Tags: java, android, bottom-sheet

I've implemented a bottom sheet in the `onCreate()` method of my activity as follows:

```
bottomSheet = new BottomSheetDialog(this);
bottomSheet.setContentView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet, null));
bottomSheet.show();
```

My activity extends `AppCompatActivity` and has a `TabLayout` and `ViewPager` in it.. pretty much a standard UI using material design.

The problem I'm having is that when `show()` is called, the status bar instantly turns black, adding jumpiness to the otherwise smooth animation of the bottom sheet expanding, not to mention altering the app's color scheme.

I would like the status bar to remain the default color associated with my theme, and darken smoothly as the bottom sheet expands.

I've done quite a bit of searching, but have not been able to find a concrete solution.

Any ideas what could be causing this and what steps, if any, I can take to fix it?

Black Status Bar (UI content removed for simplicity)
[image: Black Status Bar (UI content removed for simplicity)]

Answer (score 6):

Add the following in your styles.xml:

```
 <style name="BottomDialogTheme" parent="Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
</style>
```

You can then add this to your dialog with:

```
bottomSheet.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NORMAL, R.style.BottomDialogTheme);
```

For devices > API 20 this worked and gave a smooth transition to a darker shade of my statusBar. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

#### First, wirte a class extends BottomSheetDialog and override onCreate():

```
public class FixedBottomSheetDialog extends BottomSheetDialog {

        public FixedBottomSheetDialog(@NonNull Context context) {
            super(context);
        }


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            int screenHeight = getScreenHeight(getOwnerActivity());
            int statusBarHeight = getStatusBarHeight(getContext());
            int dialogHeight = screenHeight - statusBarHeight;
            if (getWindow() != null)
                getWindow().setLayout(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, dialogHeight == 0 ? ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT : dialogHeight);
        }

        private static int getScreenHeight(Activity activity) {
            DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
            return displaymetrics.heightPixels;
        }

        private static int getStatusBarHeight(Context context) {
            int statusBarHeight = 0;
            Resources res = context.getResources();
            int resourceId = res.getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
            if (resourceId > 0) {
                statusBarHeight = res.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
            }
            return statusBarHeight;
        }

    }
```

#### Then, set owner activity

```
    bottomSheetDialog.setOwnerActivity(this);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<style name="BottomSheetStyle" parent="BottomSheetDialogTheme">
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
</style>
```

Use backgroundDimEnabled = false and set this style to your BottomSheetDialog to disable status bar dimming if you want a full screen bottom sheet and don't need background dimming

Answer (score 1):

In `styles.xml` add:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="bottomSheetDialogTheme">@style/BaseBottomSheetDialog</item>
</style>
```

and

```
<style name="BottomSheet" parent="@style/Widget.Design.BottomSheet.Modal">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/rounded_dialog</item>
</style>

<style name="BaseBottomSheetDialog" parent="@style/Theme.Design.Light.BottomSheetDialog">
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">false</item>
    <item name="bottomSheetStyle">@style/BottomSheet</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:navigationBarColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```